# Copying the attachment from the email and renaming the text files

Tags: sql, ssis

I have three text files in email attachment, which client send us everyday via email. Right now I am manually saving the file and renaming the file and running ssis package.

Is there any way I can automatically copy all three text files, rename them, and run in ssis package?
for example
when they send attachment for example it says abc.txt, def.txt and xyz.txt , i have to rename the text file in certain location as 123.txt,456.txt and 789.txt and process the txt file

Comment: Are you asking if you can pull the attached files directly from the email and same them to some named pattern?   Or are you just trying to skip the "rename and run SSIS package" step?

Comment: when they send attachment for example it says abc.txt, def.txt and xyz.txt , i have to rename the text file in certain location as 123.txt,456.txt and 789.txt and process the txt file

Comment: You would need the ability to connect to the e-mail server, lookup the email, and download the attachment. To my knowledge, this is not possible with any of the components that come stock with SSIS. It may be possible with a custom component, but I have not attempted this. See Chris Compton's answer for pulling the files via FTP. Note: SSIS only has an FTP task - it does not support SFTP. You will need to build a custom component if security is required.